# is it possible to start a cordova project with expo?

Tags: cordova, expo

In command prompt, I tried type in `expo start` when I'm in my cordova project folder but I got this error:

Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.

is it possible to start a cordova project with expo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to integrate React Native / Expo into an existing Cordova native project. To be honest I think you will have a hard time doing this, and you're most likely better off starting it from scratch.

If you do decide to continue going down the approach of trying to build into your existing project, this guide explains how to integrate React Native into an existing app: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

And this guide explains how to use Expo libraries in an existing app: https://docs.expo.io/bare/existing-apps/